# Не работает выпадающее меню на CSS

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, поясните почему не работает выпадающее меню.
HTML

```
    <nav class="main_navigation">
      <ul class="main_menu">
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
          <ul class="dropdown_menu">
            <li class="dropdown_menu_novelty">
              <a href="#">Новинки</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="catalog.html">Сливочное</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Щербеты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Фруктовый лед</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Мелорин</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="#">О Компании</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

СSS:

```
.main_menu  {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 19px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
  }
  .dropdown_menu  {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    display: none;
  }
  .main_menu_item:first-of-type > a:hover .dropdown_menu  {
    display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли `+`:

```
.main_menu_item:first-of-type > a:hover + .dropdown_menu  {...}
```

`.dropdown_menu` находится не внутри тега `a`, а после него, поэтому нужно использовать селектор [`element+element`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)

```css
.main_menu  {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 19px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
  }
  .dropdown_menu  {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    display: none;
  }
  .main_menu_item:first-of-type > a:hover + .dropdown_menu  {
    display: block;
  }
```

```html
   <nav class="main_navigation">
      <ul class="main_menu">
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
          <ul class="dropdown_menu">
            <li class="dropdown_menu_novelty">
              <a href="#">Новинки</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="catalog.html">Сливочное</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Щербеты</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Фруктовый лед</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
              <a href="#">Мелорин</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
        </li>
        <li class="main_menu_item">
          <a href="#">О Компании</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, нет не забыл,я неправильно представлял как все работает,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я немного извратил ваш CSS и скрыл меню немного по-другому:

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main_menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 19px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropdown_menu {
  max-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.main_menu_item:first-of-type:hover .dropdown_menu {
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main_navigation">
  <ul class="main_menu">
    <li class="main_menu_item">
      <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
      <ul class="dropdown_menu">
        <li class="dropdown_menu_novelty">
          <a href="#">Новинки</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Сливочное</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
          <a href="#">Щербеты</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
          <a href="#">Фруктовый лед</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown_menu_item">
          <a href="#">Мелорин</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="main_menu_item">
      <a href="#">Доставка и оплата</a>
    </li>
    <li class="main_menu_item">
      <a href="#">О Компании</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```